# To what forms of "Where are you" will Google Hangouts afford a "Share your location" button?

Tags: geolocation, google-hangouts

When asked "Where are you now?" by another person in Google Hangouts, the app will offer an action button for you to send your location to the person:

[image: Google Hangouts: Location-aware]

What other forms of that phrase will work? So far, I know that these do, with or without the punctuation:

1. Where are you now?
2. Where are you?
3. Where you at?

Comment: @Rubén It's just as much a part of iOS and desktop as it is part of Android. I just happened to use an Android screenshot because it was available to me at the time of writing.

Comment: You should consider to add that to your question to make it clear that it's a question related to the overall system and not only for mobile apps. By the way, how can be added the location from the Hangouts apps for desktop?

Comment: @Rubén Do you know of a more appropriate place to ask about multi-platform software questions? My question is not about adding location from desktop or Android or iOS. I don't know if you can add a question from desktop or not, but I know that you can, using the desktop Hangouts, ask another person (who is using Hangouts on a mobile device) one of the questions and the button will be afforded. My question is about the invocation process, not the provision of the location.

Comment: @Rubén If you do know another more appropriate site, please suggest it so that it can be migrated there, rather than simply closing my question.

Comment: See my first comment. You could delete the question here and post it in the site suggested.

Comment: @Rubén Ok, I flagged it with a request for migration based on your comment.

Comment: May I know the reason why you want to know this? It seems impossible to know unless someone from Google discloses it (except, [they only mentioned "Where are you,"](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/6142837)). [An article from 9to5mac](http://9to5mac.com/2015/01/06/google-hangouts-ios/) shows a screenshot with **"Where?"** only. I don't use Hangouts, so I can't test it though.

Comment: @AndrewT.It's user research. I have curiosity about a grammar decision like this from a company like Google.